# More logical "if $var is defined and $var does not equal" statement in php

Tags: php, if-statement

In PHP, I have the if statement:

`FIX_RECIPE_ID && FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId`

It does what it says on the tin, though, is there a more logical way of writing this statement?

Thanks all in advance!

Comment: This statement will generate a warning if FIX_RECIPE_ID is not defined. This is not JavaScript :)

Comment: `FIX_RECIPE_ID` a constant? If so you should probably be checking `defined('FIX_RECIPE_ID')`.

Comment: @Jan, no-one has said it is JS, its PHP!

Comment: @Brad, thanks, do you know of there is a more logical way or is this the most logical?

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates I think the logic here is completely logical.

Comment: @JonathonDavidOates: Not that I can see. there's only so many ways to write "if it's defined and matches". Unless you're checking it with other values too, what you have it both brief and concise. Don't confuse performance and clarity for trying to be more witty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `FIX_RECIPE_ID` is a constant, use this syntax.

```
defined(FIX_RECIPE_ID) && (FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```

If not, make it a variable first, then use

```
isset($FIX_RECIPE_ID) && ($FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```

Answer (score 2):

Sorry to submit as an answer, but I don't have commenting privileges yet I guess.

Shiplu's answer is not completely correct. The line:

```
defined(FIX_RECIPE_ID) && (FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```

Will appear to work, but will throw a notice along the lines of `Use of undefined constant FIX_RECIPE_ID - assumed 'FIX_RECIPE_ID'` if it's not defined, and will have very unexpected behaviour (typically returning false) if it is.

The `defined` function takes the name of the constant as a string. PHP will assume you mean the string `'FIX_RECIPE_ID'` if it's not defined and work as expected (although, as mentioned, throwing a notice). If it is defined, you'll be checking whether a constant exists named after the *value* of FIX_RECIPE_ID.

Meaning when it's not defined, your check is effectively:

```
defined('FIX_RECIPE_ID') && (FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```

Which is correct and will return false. When it *is* defined, however, (let's pretend it's `10`), the check will become:

```
defined(10) && (FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```

And defined will return false. **This entire conditional will always return false.**

The correct way to use [defined](http://php.net/defined) in this context would be:

```
defined('FIX_RECIPE_ID') && (FIX_RECIPE_ID != $favouriteRecipeId)
```